# How to replace all spaces in a string with "." in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I know there is such a command. Which?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во-первых, вопрос должен быть на русском языке, а во-вторых, у строк есть метод, который так и называется replace

Comment: Please ask questions in English next time at stackoverflow (en)

Answer (score 5):

Здравствуйте чтоб поменять пробелы на любой символ нужно использовать метод строк в Python.

Метод `replace(old, new)` возвращает копию n со всеми вхождениями подстроки old, замененными на new.

Результатом выполнения следующего кода:

```
n = 'foo bar foo baz foo qux'
print(n.replace(' ', '.'))
```

будет:

```
foo.bar.foo.baz.foo.qux
```